# Update styles set in shadow dom via CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, shadow-dom

This question applies to Ionic, but its answer could apply more generally to CSS. I'm not sure.

I'm using ionic 4 which creates shadow DOM elements that have specific styles. I have the following:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating">Floating Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I want the "Floating Label" text to move further to the left than usual when it's floating. I can do this pretty easily with styles on the label itself.

However, the shadow DOM divs created under `ion-item` have their own styles that include `overflow: hidden`. I have not found a way to update these styles from my stylesheet. I've tried using `/deep/` and various other selectors, but these do not seem to work and support for them also seems to be removed. I understand that you can use CSS variables, but this particular property `overflow` is not set by a variable. I also understand that you can use the DOM to inject styles into the shadow DOM, but I want to avoid doing this since I would have to do it somewhere in every component rather than being able to do it once across the app.

Is there any way to override styles set in a shadow DOM using CSS if variables are not available?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`:host`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) css selector? I can confirm that the `/deep/` and `.cla >>> elem` approach used to work before they deprecated it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the ng-deep selector to manipulate DOM elements style directly.

```
::ng-deep {
 .your-class { // Used to contain your deep change to a localized node
    your style
}
```

Angular guidelines : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: From the doc you linked" *The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being **removed from major browsers** and tools. As such we plan to **drop support in Angular** (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.*

Comment: Yes, but it has been like this for more than 1 year now and still no update so it's still the best use-case possible :)

Comment: @Zze is there an alternative?